# Где должны стоять запятые? (желательно с объяснением)

Tags: пунктуация

Поначалу конь не произвёл на Степана впечатления (1) но (2) когда вороной подбежал ближе (3) и Степан увидел крутую шею и широкую грудь (4) то он невольно залюбовался великолепным скакуном.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что Д/З

Answer (score 1):

Корректно: Поначалу конь не произвёл на Степана впечатления(,) но  когда вороной подбежал ближе  и Степан увидел крутую шею и широкую грудь(,) то 
он невольно залюбовался великолепным скакуном.

1) Запятая на стыке двух союзов не ставится (в вашем примере союзы **но - когда**), если после первого союза следует вторая часть двойного союза - **то** ( когда то).

> Ср.: Поначалу конь не произвёл на Степана впечатления,  **но  когда** вороной подбежал ближе (3) и Степан увидел крутую шею и широкую грудь,  **то** он невольно залюбовался великолепным скакуном.

2) Запятая в пункте 2 и 3 также не нужна, поскольку **между двумя придаточными, соединенными одиночными соединительными или разделительными союзами и, или, либо, да (в значении «и»), запятая не ставится (при этом подчинительный союз или союзное слово может и не повторяться):**

> Ср.: Поначалу конь не произвёл на Степана впечатления, но **когда вороной 
>   подбежал ближе  и (когда) Степан увидел крутую шею и широкую грудь,то он невольно залюбовался великолепным скакуном..**

Подробнее здесь: [Розенталь. Д.Э. Справочник по русскому языку: орфография и пунктуация.](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137)